# boostrap accordion changing url

Tags: reactjs

I am using reactjs for view and angularjs for routing and others. Using ngReact for managing both.

I need to implement boostrap's accordion which has a 'a' tag in it. as soon as click on it, url changes which forces my state to change. I tried writing a function onClick where i was preventing the default, but using debugger I found that even before control comes angular already has changed the url. any work around it.

accordion html snippet:

```
<div className="row test">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"
                       href="#collapseOne" onClick={this.collapse.bind(this)}>
                        Usage
                    </a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    hihihi
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

reactjs onClick function :

```
collapse(e) {
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    return e;
}
```